# Rails 3.1: jQuery UI methods not defined in my code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have some strange problem with using jQuery UI in my Rails 3.1 application.
I've added jQuery UI by Assets Pipeline, all code executed without errors, but when I'm trying to use UI methods in my code, I have "no method" error.

It seems that UI extends some another jQuery object.

Here is content of application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ui/jquery_ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

jquery_ui dir is located in /vedor.

Comment: How does the UI code looks like? Maybe it isn't an assets problem ...

Comment: When I use jquery ui from ujs, it is simple uglyfied jQuery UI 1.8.16, but without any additional widgets. But even $.Widget and $.ui objects cannot be found in my code.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. I tried to include jquery-ui using javascript_tag too. But it did not work. jquery-ui.js gets loaded into the browser ( Ref:firebug net tab ) but I get function not found error. I pasted the entire jquery-ui.js code in my console and then executed $("div").slider(); and it worked. Then I wrote an alert("hi"); in application.js and this line was not there in the application.js file that got loaded into browser. I tried "rake assets:clean" then "rake assets:precompile" then restarted the server. and nothing worked. :( Solution please....

Answer (score 2):

The [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) gem already contains jquery-ui. So it works fine just with:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

Comment: Are you accidentally including another instance of jQuery or jQuery UI elsewhere? Or an additional library that's creating a namespace conflict?

Comment: No. As I can see in Chromedeveloper tool, all files that have downloaded to client is jquery, jquery_ujs, jquery-ui and google maps library.

Comment: Ok, but have You tried this order - jquery_ujs before jquery-ui ? It's important, as far as I remember. If You do, ignore this comment :)